# select.poll doesn't detect available read unless I sleep for some time

Tags: python, select, polling

#### Context

I would like to use select.poll to know when data is available to read, buffer this data, and use said buffer as a subprocess' stdin.

The data is being dumped at equally spaced intervals. (see execution example)
It's important that reading data in the main script is non-blocking, so subprocess can be executed from there.

#### Problem

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# file: wrap.py
#

import select
import sys
import time

max_retries = 2
timeout = 300

fd_stdin = sys.stdin.fileno()
poll = select.poll()
poll.register(fd_stdin, select.POLLIN)

tries = 0
while True:
    events = poll.poll(timeout)

    # means we timeout
    if len(events) == 0:
        print('timeout')
        tries += 1
        if tries >= max_retries:
           print('sleeping')
           time.sleep(1)
        continue

    tries = 0
    for fd, event in events:
        if fd != fd_stdin or event & select.POLLIN != 1:
            print(f'Unknown event {event}')
            continue

        print(sys.stdin.readline(), flush=True)
```

To test the program I run this, to simulate the equally spaced interval dump.

```bash
while true; do for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done; sleep 10; done | ./wrap.py
```

But it doesn't work as expected (or I don't understand how it is supposed to work)
[image: output of above command]

What confuse me the most is that if I had a small sleep directive in the bash while loop, it does what I want.

```bash
while true; do for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 0.01; done; sleep 10; done | ./wrap.py
```

[image: output expected if using sleep 0.01]

I even try using a python script as the dump block, but it doesn't change a thing (still need to sleep to get expected result).

Edited to add the python echo script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

while True:
    for i in range(1000):
        print(i)
        # this line allow the code to behave as expected.
        # time.sleep(0.01) 
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: This is confusing, I would assume that the small sleep act as a forceful flush. There might batching done by the OS ?

Answer (score 2):

First, your shebang (#!) must be in line 1 , not line 4.
Nobody will be able to replicate the problem without fixing that.
Second, I think there is a flaw in your original bash script. The way it's written, the CPU will execute at full speed to generate a bunch of 10 consecutive lines and then sleep 10 seconds.
I suspect that's not what you were expecting.

Now, why do we have only a 1 before all those timeouts?
It's complex. Please stay with me.
At time 0: your bash script generate 10 lines. A few microseconds later, poll() returns an event, so your program call readline() to extract the first line. But the other 9 lines stay in readline() buffer, waiting to be read, and the stdin buffer is now empty.
For the next 10 seconds, poll only return timeouts since there is nothing new in stdin buffer.
At time 10, your bash script generate a new bunch of 10 lines and that generate an event. Your program call readline() and get a 2. That line is from bunch #1 (still residing in readline buffer). The readline buffer now contain
18 lines and stdin buffer is empty.
Next event will be at time 30.
Et cetera, et cetera.
Addition of a small sleep in the bash script change the dynamic because poll will now have time to generate an event for each line so your program will generate a readline() for each line. But your program will still be 'fragile' because there's still a risk that the stdin buffer may contain 2 lines. These 2 lines will be transferred together to readline buffer but readline() will only consume 1 line. So lines will accumulate in readline buffer.

Conclusion:
There are 2 bugs:

- one in the bash script. It's the cause of confusion.
- second: every time you get an event you must completely consume readline buffer. It not easy since readline may block, waiting for an EOL.
  I would suggest to do a read() instead of readline() and use find() or splitlines() to extract lines from your buffer.

And you will be able to remove tries and max_retries.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot ! Make a lot more sense now.
Will the CPU "bundle" process is independent of the language ? Because I encountered the same issue while writing an echo script in python instead of the bash commands.

Comment: Python may also exhibit same pattern. If you post your Python statement, I may have analyze it.

Comment: Though, read(-1) is a blocking call, and if my size is too small, the problem will now be that I'll be lacking some data.

Comment: Edited original post to include the python statement.

Comment: For blocking, you may use os.set_blocking( fd, False). It work for Unix and Linux. And probably MacOs. For Windows, I don't know. For size, -1 means "everything available".

Comment: Your Python script will create the same problem. It will generate bunches of 10 lines at a time.